# How to retrieve translation from TextBlob translate

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I'm using TextBlob to translate a sentence, and for the life of me I can't figure out how to retrieve the translated text as a string. For example

```
from textblob import TextBlob
trans = TextBlob('Hello World')
foo = trans.translate(to='la')
```

How can I assign the translated text as a variable? Looking through the docs doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, I got it, foobar = str(foo). That's all that is needed. foobar is now just a regular old string.